# ThumbnailExtension_macOS taking too much CPU

Tags: macos, ventura

After upgrading to macOS Ventura i am having performance issue with my MacBook Pro machine.

In activity monitor ,ThumbnailExtension_macOS keeps consuming 98+ CPU always.

```
 ThumbnailExtension_macOS (Not Responding)  99.1    6:36:38.43  2   0   0.0 0.00    1126    ABC     0 bytes 0 bytes 0 bytes Intel   No  Yes Yes (null)  No  0 bytes 0   0 bytes 0   0 bytes 0 bytes 0 bytes No  -   0 bytes 0 bytes No  (null)
```

I tried killing the process even restarted many times but no ease.
Configuration:
2.6 GHz 6 core Intel Code i7
16 GB RAM
MacBook Pro 2019

Comment: Is this extension part of a browser you are using? Did you try to disable it there?

Comment: I am not sure. I have only Adblock and Grammarly installed.  To me this looks like some macos-related process.

Comment: Without further information it's hard to diagonse. Can you reboot and login without starting any applications and check whether the process is already running? And then start your browser and check again?

Comment: It restarted and killed multiple times but no help. I gathered more info on this process as below:

Parent Process : launchd(1)
Open files :

Library/Containers/com.apple.QuickLookThumbnailing.extension.ThumbnailExtension-macOS/Data

/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLookThumbnailing.framework/Versions/A/PlugIns/ThumbnailExtension_macOS.appex/Contents/MacOS/ThumbnailExtension_macOS

/System/Library/Fonts/LastResort.otf

Comment: ThumbnailExt is taking 99,6% of my CPU in effect committing terrorism against me as a paying customer. I wish I had stayed with Microsoft